# Error 404 on a html link

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I created this:

```html
<a href="~/Areas/Admin/Views/Event/Index.cshtml"><span>Events:</span>&nbsp;<span class="badge">@ViewBag.Count</span></a>
```

to count the Number of tables. When I try to navigate to that reference: `~/Areas/Admin/Views/Event/Index.cshtml` i get the following:

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

I have verified it, I have changed it to: `@Html.ActionLink("Event", "Index")` to: `@Url.View("Event", "Index")` and many more, I've viewed carefully the path, I've removed the Authorize from the controller and searched on internet but nothing.

Can anybody give me some kind of advice?

Comment: Have you tried it without ~

Comment: You don't link directly to views.  You link to actions.  Remember that you're using MVC.

Comment: If a take the path off it shows the same thing!

Comment: You should use @Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") in this case

Comment: @Amy please view the question, I allready did that: "@html.ActionLink("Event", "Index")".

Comment: @Esko it's the same. display error.

Comment: @JonA What is the output html now?

Comment: You cannot link cshtml directly. Must be ~/Controller/Action

Comment: @Yuri something like this: "~/Event/Index" I have allready tryed without success.

Comment: You need to give us more to go on than "it gives me an error".  Explain what its actually doing, we aren't going to continue shooting in the dark.

Comment: Here Amy this is the error that I get: "HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly." it was in the original question posted, so sorry about that.

Comment: What's the name of the controller and the action you are trying?

Comment: What about this: `@Html.ActionLink("url text", "Index", "Event", new { area = "Admin" }, null);`

Comment: Why isn't my answer the accepted answer? I posted the correct solution. The answer you have as accepted will give a run-time error due to an incorrect overload of Html.ActionLink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Areas.  Then you need to use the correct form of the `Html.ActionLink` overload.

Here is what you need:

```
@Html.ActionLink("url text", "Index", "Event", new { area = "Admin" }, null);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your action and controller are backwards.  The first argument is also the label.  See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String%29):

> public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
>       this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>       string linkText,
>       string actionName,
>       string controllerName

Your current code is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Event", "Index")
```

However, you have the order wrong and you're missing the label.  Assuming your controller is `EventController`, this would be

```
@Html.ActionLink("the link label", "Index", "Event")
```

Comment: Sorry Amy, but it's the same it shows the same error.

Comment: This is very frustrating!

Comment: What does it actually render as?  "It doesn't work" doesn't help me understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: For your last post with the link label it display's the following error:

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: **What does the link actually render as?**  Please give us more to go on.  Your updated error message indicates the link worked and you're now having a problem server-side.

Comment: @JonA When you run your application.. right-click the link and hit Inspect.. or View Source even.. and post what that link is being rendered as.

Comment: @JonA try: `@Html.ActionLink("url text", "Index", "Event", new { area = "Admin" }, null);`

Comment: @JonA I added my answer, please mark as accepted so that this question can be seen as answered

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the controller inside the area "Admin" is called event, the Razor code for generating the correct link will be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("url text", "Index", "Event", new { area = "Admin" });
// Note: You might have problem with the "badge" class
```

using a classic html url:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Event", new { area = "Admin" })'>
     <span>Events:</span>&nbsp;<span class="badge">@ViewBag.Count</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Do you have a controller class called "EventController" in your "Admin" Area? Do you have an action called "Index" in that controller?

Comment: The first action link you posted is incorrect.. there is no overload that accepts a `string,string,string,RouteValueDictionary`.. you need to add html attributes.. like so: `@Html.ActionLink("url text", "Index", "Event", new { area = "Admin" }, null);`